# Cannot reinitalize Sortable after ajax content update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rubaxa-sortable

I'm using `Sortable` to organise lists inside of parent groupings, which themselves are also sortable, similar to the *multi* example on their [demo page](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/), but with text. This works fine and uses code along the lines of:

```
var globObj = {};

function prepSortCats() {

    globObj.subCatsGroup = [];

    // Changing parent group order

    globObj.sortyMainCats = Sortable.create(catscontainer, {
        // options here omitted from example
        onUpdate: function( /**Event*/ evt) {
            // Send order to database. Works fine.
        }
    });

    // Changing sub list order

    globObj.subCatsGroup.forEach.call(document.getElementById('catscontainer').getElementsByClassName('subcatlist'), function(el) {
        var sortySubCats = Sortable.create(el, {
            // options here from example
            onUpdate: function( /**Event*/ evt) {
                // Send order to database. Works fine.
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Which is called when the page loads using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Sortable
    prepSortCats();
});
```

All good so far. However, the user can introduce new elements into any of the lists (sub or parent). In brief, any new elements added by the user are first added to the database, then the relevant section of the page is refreshed using `ajax` to pull the updated content from the database and display that. The user sees their newly added items added to one of the existing lists. `Ajax` call is as follows:

```
function refreshCategories() {
    var loadUrl = "page that pulls lists from database and formats it";
    $("#catscontainer")
        .html(ajax_load)
        .load(loadUrl);
    return false;
};
```

This works fine too. Except, `Sortable` no longer works. I can't drag any lists. My first thought was to destroy the existing `Sortable` instances and reinitialize them. Right after I called `refreshCategories()` I call the following:

```
if(globObj.sortyMainCats.length !== 0) {
    globObj.sortyMainCats.destroy();
}

if(globObj.subCatsGroup.length !== 0) {
    var i;
    for (i = globObj.subCatsGroup.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        globObj.subCatsGroup[i].destroy();
        globObj.subCatsGroup.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

prepSortCats();
```

But `Sortable` still has no effect. I introduced the global object (although controversial) so that I could target the `Sortable` instances outside their scope but I appear to have overlooked something. Any ideas? Apologies for not providing a working example. As I make various `ajax` calls to a server, I don't think this is possible here.

## Update

I'm clearly misunderstanding some action that's taking place. Well, I should preface that by saying I missed that I could still organise the group/parent lists after reloading a section of the page by `aja`x with `refreshCategories()`. This is very much a secondary action to being able to sort the sub lists, which is what I noticed was broken and remains so.

But it did point out that although the entirety of `$("#catscontainer")` was being replaced with a refreshed version of the lists (and that's all it contains, list elements), `Sortable` still had some sort of instance running on it. I was under the understanding that it was somehow tied to the elements that were removed. Now I'm a bit more lost on how to get Sortable to either: (a) just start from scratch on the page, performing `prepSortCats()` as if it was a fresh page load and removing any previous `Sortable` instance, or (b) getting the remaining `Sortable` instance, after the `ajax` call to recognise the added elements.

### Update 2

Making some progress.

Through trial and error I've found that right after calling `refreshCategories()`, calling `globObj.sortyMainCats.destroy()` is preventing even the group lists from being ordered. Then if I call `prepSortCats()` after this, I can move them again. But not the sub lists.

This isn't conclusive but it looks like I'm successfully destroying and reinitializing `Sortable`, which was my goal, but something about the `ajax` loaded elements isn't working with `Sortable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the answer in the wrong place, being sure it was an issue with `ajax` loaded content and the dom having some inconsistencies with what `Sortable` expected.

Turns out it was an asynchronous problem. Or, to put it simpler, the section of the page being loaded by `ajax` wasn't quite ready when `Sortable` was being asked to be reinitalized.

For anyone having the same trouble, I changed:

```
$("#catscontainer")
    .html(ajax_load)
    .load(loadUrl);
```

to

```
$("#catscontainer")
    .html(ajax_load)
    .load(loadUrl, function() {
         reinitSortable();
    });
```

where `reinitSortable()` is just a function that fires off the `destroy` and `prepSortCats()` functions similar to how they're displayed above.